# Can I use both redux and flux in single react native project?

Tags: react-native, redux, flux

I am new to react native. Could any one please suggest me, can I use both flux and redux in a single app?

Comment: Have you ever used redux or flux before? And do you know the `context` API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, their is nothing stopping you doing that, but carefully consider what state you put in each location